# Как изменить background image через каждые 30 секунд из базы по очереди?

Tags: jquery, php, javascript, css

Здравствуйте, как изменить background image через каждые 30 секунд из базы по очереди? Из одной папки. Например чтоб облегчить задачу можно ставить от 1-го до 10 например и что он менял от 1.jpg до 10.jpg

Comment: Этот вопрос решен или нет? Или вы хотели, чтобы за вас написали весь код? Или какая у вас тактика с «25% принятых» ответов?

Answer (score 1):

Массив (если названия изображений произвольные, но, если у вас от 1 до 10, то не надо массив), setTimeout на `30e3` миллисекунд, инкремент, `jQuery`, `$.css('background-image', 'url(' + n + '.jpg)')`. Всё.

Answer (score 0):

'

```
function setBackground( n ) {

    var maxImages = 10, path = '/path/to/images/';
    var element = document.getElementById('targetElement');
    n = n || 1;

    element.style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + path + n + '.jpg")';

    (new Image()).src = path + ((n >= maxImages)? 1 : ++n) + '.jpg'; 
    setTimeout('setBackground(' + n + ')', 30000);

}
```